# Example of convex function with empty subdifferential at some point

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be a normed space and $C$ an open convex subset of $X$. Let $f: C \to \mathbb R$ be convex. If $f$ is continuous at some point in $C$, then $f$ has non-empty subdifferential at all points in $C$. If $X$ is finite-dimensional, then $f$ is continuous.

> Could you provide an example of a convex function $f$ that has empty subdifferential at some point?

Comment: Take $f$ equal to a discontinuous linear functional.

Comment: We can find an example in a finite-dimensional setting; for example the function $f(x) = \begin{cases}  -\log(x), & \quad x>0 \\ 0, \quad x = 0 \\ \infty, &\quad x < 0 \end{cases}$ has an empty subdifferential at $x=0$.

Comment: @littleO I'm looking for a convex function $f$ that takes values in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample for which $f$ has some "problems", since it is defined on an incomplete space.

We take $X = \ell^1$, but we equip it with the norm from $\ell^2$, i.e.,
$$
\|x\|_X := \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 \right)^{1/2}.$$
Now, we define $f(x) := \| x \|_{\ell^1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| \in \mathbb R$ for all $x \in X$.
Then, $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$ has the following properties:
convex (clear), lower semicontinuous (using, e.g., Fatou's lemma)
but
discontinuous everywhere (rather straightforward).
Moreover, one can show (recall that $X^*$ can be identified with $\ell^2$)
$$
\partial f(x) =
\{ y \in \ell^2 \mid y_n \in \partial |\cdot|(x_n) \;\forall n \in \mathbb N\}
$$
and this, in particular, yields
$$
\partial f(x) \ne \emptyset
$$
if and only if $x \in c_c$ (subspace of finite sequences).

Answer (score 0):

> In the special case when $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, the set-valued map $\partial_Pf: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d), x \mapsto \partial_Pf(x) $ takes nonempty, compact, and convex values and is upper semicontinuous and locally bounded.

From [Discontinuous Dynamical Systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4518905), Proposition 9, Point 2.

Answer (score -1):

I formalize @daw's comment as below.

---

Let $f:X \to \mathbb R$ be a discontinuous linear functional. We will prove that $\partial f (a) = \emptyset$ for all $a \in X$. Assume the contrary that $x^* \in \partial f (a)$ for some $a \in X$. Then
$$
f(x)-f(a) =\langle f, x-a \rangle \ge \langle x^*, x-a \rangle \quad \forall x \in X.
$$

It follows that $x^* \le f$. We define $g:X \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x) :=f(x)-f(0)$. Then $g$ is linear. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475287/let-f-g-be-affine-and-f-g-their-induced-linear-maps-if-f-le-g-then) result, $g=x^*$. Hence $g$ and thus $f$ are continuous. This is a contradiction.